# pip3 won't install python bindings for VLC

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc

Can't seem to get the Python3 bindings for VLC functioning.
I'm doing `pip3 install python_vlc` which results in:

```
Collecting python-vlc
Installing collected packages: python-vlc
Successfully installed python-vlc-1.1.2
```

So, when I do `import vlc` it gives me the following error:

```
>>> import vlc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vlc.py", line 173, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vlc.py", line 165, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL('libvlc.dylib')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(libvlc.dylib, 6): image not found
```

I tried looking for a solution online, but can't seem to find the cause.

Comment: It's not something I've had to fix directly, but it looks like `dlopen` can't find `libvlc.dylib`, so that will depend on where vlc is installed. Mine's in `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlc.dylib` and the python module appears to work without error. `man dyld` and search for `@rpath` for hints about how to look in more places to find libraries

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found the problem...
I tried uninstalling python-vlc via `pip3 uninstall python-vlc` and uninstall the VLC app with AppZapper to completely remove everything. After this I reinstalled it, it worked so I can do `import vlc` in commandline now.

**Update**: so after I did that I ran into another issue. I got this error: `core libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation.`
Added the following line to my .bash_profile:
`export VLC_PLUGIN_PATH=$VLC_PLUGIN_PATH:/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins`
which fixed it.